# How to pass multiple generics to vsim using -g switch in Modelsim?

Tags: tcl, vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to pass multiple VHDL generics to the testbench in Modelsim 10.7b using -g switch in the vsim command. How do I pass multiple generic where all the generics are defined in another string/file.

in short : When I use

`set generics  "-gHEIGHT=1 -gWIDTH=2"
vsim $generic work.test`

only the first generic, i.e., HEIGHT is getting changed. WIDTH is not getting the value 2. It remains at the value initialised at the entity.

test.vhd file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is

  generic (
    HEIGHT : integer := 0;
    WIDTH  : integer := 0);

  port (
    clk : in std_logic);

end entity test;

architecture arch of test is

begin  -- architecture arch



end architecture arch;
```

used commands to run the sim :

```
vlib work
vmap work work
vcom test.vhd
set generics  "-gHEIGHT=1 -gWIDTH=2"
```

vsim command where both generics are passed to the vhdl file successfully using -g switch :

```
vsim -gHEIGHT=1 -gWIDTH=2 work.test
```

vsim command where only first generic in the string *generic* is passed to the vhdl..i.e only HEIGHT is passed:

```
vsim $generics  work.test
```

I'm trying to pass multiple (~10) generics from python via vsim command. So I cannot list the generics name in the vsim command which executes the simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass multiple arguments contained in a single variable to a command, expand the variable using `{*}`:

```
vsim {*}$generics work.test
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked! Just an additional question, do you happen to know how do I pass other arguments of the vsim. For example : `vsim -wlf test.wlf -c -do run.do` doesn't actually creates a wlf named test.wlf. I had to add it as vsim -wlf test.wlf work.test

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a clue about modelsim. Your first question was really just plain Tcl, which is why I was able to answer that.

Comment: @Rakend in your first `vsim` command in your comment (`vsim -wlf test.wlf -c -do run.do`), you don't specify a design unit, like you do in the second command (`vsim -wlf test.wlf work.test`), where `work.test` is the library and design unit. Maybe that's why it didn't create a WLF, because it didn't know what design unit to simulate.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the `-f` argument to the `vsim` command and specify a file containing various `vsim` arguments, including generic arguments. E.g.:

```
vsim -f arg_file.txt
```

Then your file (arg_file.txt in this case) can contain your generic arguments or whatever else you might need:

```
-gHEIGHT=1 -gWIDTH=2
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with `eval "vsim $generics  work.test"`

Even though Modelsim evaluates this statement and displays it as `vsim -gHEIGHT=1 -gWIDTH=2 work.test` on command execution, looks like vsim parser is not taking this as an argument.